# Using "m" prefix for variables in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, coding-style

Using "m" prefix for variable names became usual in programming, mainly in Android, but since Kotlin arrived, this minor thing bothers me a bit.

Setting and getting variables with "m" prefix doesn't seem really nice, because in Java we create (and name) our setters and getters, so we can omit the "m", but this doesn't happen in Kotlin, unless we walk in the opposite of conventions and repeat Java's technique.

Java:

```java
public class Foo {
    private String mName;

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("Foo");
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
data class Foo(val mName: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo()
    foo.mName = "Foo"  // "m" prefix doesn't fit
}
```

What should we do? Is there a new convention to follow?

Comment: Honestly, I never understood why people used an `m` prefix in Java. I never did that.

Comment: This practice is called Hungarian Notation. It does not seem to make much sense in a strongly typed language.

Comment: It is very common in Android Java as the SDK guys introduced it as a guideline a while back.

Comment: Also I voted this up as it's the first result on Google for Kotlin property naming. It does lead to the official docs eventually, so I'd say it's a good question.

Comment: m is still better than underscore. But both are remnants of other ages and even languages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A good reference from Android

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#naming_2

> Special prefixes or suffixes, like those seen in the examples name_,
> mName, s_name, and kName, are not used except in the case of backing
> properties (see “[Backing properties](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#backing-properties)”).

Answer (score 11):

Per the [Android Kotlin Style Guide](https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html#naming-1):

> Special prefixes or suffixes, like those seen in the examples `name_`, `mName`, `s_name`, and `kName`, are not used except in the case of backing properties (see “[Backing properties](https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html#backing-properties)”).

Therefore you should not use the "m" prefix for variables in Kotlin.

Answer (score 5):

I actually don’t think it’s good practise to have prefixed variables in the public API, thus `foo.mName = "Foo"` would be undesirable. For *private* fields this would be acceptable though.

The official [conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) for the Kotlin language say:

> **Names for backing properties**
>
> If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use an **underscore** as the prefix for the name of the private property:

```
class C {
    private val _elementList = mutableListOf<Element>()

    val elementList: List<Element>
         get() = _elementList
}
```