# Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to a class which has field mActivity pointing to Activity)

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

I have a class which holds data used by different activities and which updates the data by global timers. It also holds a reference to the current activity.

```
class AdsManager : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    private var mActivity : Activity? = null
    
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) { }
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { }
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        if(activity is AppCompatActivity) {
            mActivity = activity
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) { }
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) { }
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) { }
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) { }
}
```

`mActivity` is used for example to show [RewardedAds](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded) or [InterstitialAds](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial).

Since it is used globally I've put it into the Application companion object.

```
class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var adsManager: AdsManager
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        adsManager = AdsManager()
    }
}
```

But lint shows this warning

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
> reference to AdsManager which has field mActivity pointing to
> Activity); this is a memory leak

If user closes an activity then a new activity is started and the reference to the old one is replaced. So how a memory leak is possible here? Is there a better solution for this?

**Update**

Would it make any difference if the field is made non-static like below?

```
class App : Application() {
    lateinit var adsManager: AdsManager
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        adsManager = AdsManager()
    }
}
```

It can still be accessed from any activity as `(application as App).adsManager`, but there is no lint warning anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056248/using-m-prefix-for-variables-in-kotlin/48056288

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to keep mActivity? All callback function carries Activity as the first parameter to tell you which activity is being created/started/resumed etc.

Keeping mActivity causes memory leak -- when the activity is closed by the user, your lifecycle callback still keeps a reference to it, so it is not considered as "not used any more" and will not be destroyed. This is a memory leak.

If you really need mActivity, then your design has a problem.

Comment: mActivity is used for example to show [RewardedAds](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded). When an activity is closed by the user, then another activity is started and the old reference is replaced.